# Can someone explain the Fresnel diffraction simply?

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, diffraction

I have been researching and found multiple equations. There are ones for the Arago's spot, Fresnel number, Fresnel diffraction, Fresnel integral. They often lead to other wave behaviors which confuses me. I am confused what is the concept behind these wave behaviors. Specifically the Fresnel integral and Fresnel diffraction. The integral is used for what exactly and what is the concept of the Fresnel diffraction? English it not my first language so I get thrown off easily so that is why I ask if anyone can simplify it a little bit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. On highschool level imagine the light follows the path of shortest (optical) distance, which is called [optical path length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_path_length). This optical distance is refractive index times "normal" distance. The [Huygens principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) describes the light an an interface. E.g. every point at a slit is the emitter of a new spherical wave. The sum of the wave gives the Fresnel diffraction.
2. On college level the wave take all possible paths simultaneously and even one photon interfere with itsself. See [Path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). This explains the double slit experiment with single photons and even electrons and molecules as large as buckminster balls with 60 atoms.

Comment: Mathematically, the Huygens principle is a postulate, and Fresnel diffraction is math based on that postulate.